# Simple proof about XOR, (possibly a duplicate question)

Tags: logic

Prove Whether this statement is True or False:

Other than solving by Truth Table

If  $A \oplus b = A \oplus C$ then $A=C$

---

I saw this question online and I've been thinking about it for days now and I'm pretty sure this question may have been asked already but I didn't it so far,

Thanks

Comment: Unless if I am missing something, this only seems to be true when $b=C$.

Comment: Yes, but how to prove it other than using truth table. I think you're saying to prove it using indirect proof?

Comment: It suffices to prove only the case where $A$, $b$ and $C$ are single-bits (assuming a bitwise XOR).  You can then further reduce this down into two cases: where $b=C$, and where $b= \neg C$.

Comment: If you consider arithmetic mod 2 (in $\mathbb{Z}_2$) then XOR is really just addition. I think that simplifies the picture a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\;\oplus\;$ ('exclusive or') is just the opposite of boolean equivalence, which I usually write as $\;\equiv\;$.  So $\;\oplus\;$ is just $\;\not\equiv\;$.

Since $\;\equiv\;$ is associative (which you may or not be allowed to use, if not you'll have to prove it first), it is allowed to leave out parentheses in the middle lines below, and calculate
\begin{align}
& (A \not\equiv b) \equiv (A \not\equiv C) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"negate both sides of $\;\equiv\;$"} \\
& A \equiv b \equiv A \equiv C \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"symmetry of (middle) $\;\equiv\;$"} \\
& A \equiv A \equiv b \equiv C \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"simplify"} \\
& b \equiv C \\
\end{align}

Note that if you're allowed to use that $\;\equiv\;$ and $\;\not\equiv\;$ are *mutually* associative, then the proof becomes even shorter.